# Using recursion to find number of spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, recursion, trees

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTenv.png)

I need to use recursion to determine the number of spanning trees. I know the Proposition for this is as follows :

> Let  τ(G) denote the number of spanning trees of a graph G. if e∈E(G) is not a loop, then τ(G) = τ(G-e) + τ(G*e))

I am not sure how to implement this.

Comment: You need to remove $3$ edges out of the $8$. Considering the need for connectivity, there are $20$ obvious and $3$ less obvious disconnecting sets. I'll think about your recursion approach later.

Comment: What if I wanted to use matrix methods?